# Don't redirect from http to https

Tags: java, deployment, localhost, wildfly, war

my server is redirecting from http to https. I'd like to allow access to my application both with http and https. how could I do that? In my wildfly 8.2 log there are these two lines:

> JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /0.0.0.0:8818
>
> JBAS017519: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on /0.0.0.0:9181

If I type http://localhost:8818/myapp/index.html, it redirects to https://localhost:9181/myapp/index.html

How could I avoid it?

Comment: You might need to change your standalone.xml configuration to allow a http and a https connection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apache or nginx ?

In apache it would be something like this in the config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```